# <CFContent type=text/x-javascript> and Ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, content-type, cfc

I am using Ajax on a CFC file. I can't get the result from the function that I am calling from Ajax. I set a debug message (Alert()), but can't see it. Any suggestion?

```
function getDelegateChartAcct(LocFund){
   alert("#Arguments.PIUniversalID#");
   alert($F("DelegateFund"));                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  new Ajax.Request( "?method=displayDelegateChartAcct",
            {
              parameters : {
                            PIUniversalID: "#Arguments.PIUniversalID#",
                            PILocFund: $F("DelegateFund")                                                                                
                            },
                            method : "post"
                             }
               );
     }

     <cffunction name="displayDelegateChartAcct" access="remote" output="true" 
      returntype="void">
          <CFArgument name="PIUniversalID" type="string" required="true" />
          <CFArgument name="LocFund" required="true" type="String" />

      <CFSET var chartacctlist = runChartAcctDelegationQuery 
                  (#Arguments.PIUniversalID#, #Arguments.LocFund#)>

        <CFContent type="text/x-javascript">               
          alert(“Hi”);     
          //      delegateChartAcctList();
          //      $("DelegateChartAcct").
           //     <CFOutput query="chartacctlist">           
            //     $("DelegateChartAcct").insert( new Element(
                    "option", { value : "#JSStringFormat( chart_acct )#", selected : 
            //        "selected" } ).update( "#JSStringFormat( chart_acct )#" ) );                                                        
            //                            </CFOutput>


            </cffunction>
```

Thanks,
Kefang

Comment: returntype="void" specifically tells your cfc to return nothing.

Answer (score 7):

You are not returning anything from the CFC (and you can't run JavaScript inside the function you are calling remotely, either).

You have 2 ways you can handle this:

1. Load the form (or element) you want by making a remote call to a .cfm file that builds the form (or element) you want. You can use *$("{place form will be displayed}").load("{url to .cfm page})* and jQuery will make an HTTP request adn load the result in the DOM element that matches the selector.
2. Change your CFC to return the query and populate the select box on the client side using JavsScript. (This is what I would do)

Your code would look like this:

```
<cffunction name="displayDelegateChartAcct" access="remote" output="true" returntype="query">
      <cfargument name="PIUniversalID" type="string" required="true" />
      <cafrgument name="LocFund" required="true" type="String" />

  <cfset var chartacctlist = runChartAcctDelegationQuery (#Arguments.PIUniversalID#, #Arguments.LocFund#)>
    <cfreturn chartacctlist />
</cfcomponent>
```

You could then use the following to load that data (looks like Prototype based on the syntax):

```
new Ajax.Request( "?method=displayDelegateChartAcct&returnFormat=json",
    {
        parameters : {
            PIUniversalID: "#Arguments.PIUniversalID#",
            PILocFund: $F("DelegateFund")                                                                                
        },
        method : "post",
        onSuccess: function(response) {
                // code in here will populate select
        }
     }
 );
```

The 'returnFormat=json' tells ColdFusion to return the results as JSON.

You would just need a JS handler to take that data and use it to populate the SELECT box.